# Python 2.7 : How to read an excel which has a table inside a cell

Tags: python, excel, object, ms-word

I have this [weird excel](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=15454226257967273939) which has a Microsoft-word table inside a cell. I tried zip and unzip to extract this cell. I find the table in embeddings folder as MS-Word file using below code ::

```
myExcelFile = zipfile.ZipFile("weirdexcel.xlsx") 
myExcelFile.extractall("myFolder")
myExcelFile.close()
```

Now my question is how to find out that this MS-word file belongs to row which has ID L_SpVer_1133 ? **I need to find a connection between MS-word files and their rows(which row they belong to in Excel file)** in case there are lot of rows with embedded tables in weirdexcel.xlsx.

Comment: Can you specify what you see, what error you get whenever you try to read your excel file into Python?

Comment: There is no error. Above code works! My question is how to find out that this MS-word file belongs to row which has ID L_SpVer_1133 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built-in contains function:

```
dataset.str.contains('L_SpVer_1133', regex=False)
```

Comment: Surely this is a comment, not an answer?

Comment: I dont get any error. My code works! My question is how to find out that this MS-word file belongs to row which has ID L_SpVer_1133 ?

Comment: Please explain how  to use your code in my code and how it solves the problem.

Comment: This code shows the row(/s) that contain the string that youre looking for ('L_SpVer_1133' in this case).

Comment: I want to know the row which contains the MS-word file.

Comment: So not all of your rows contain a table you mean? Can you please give an example of your dataframe so I can interpret your question better?

Comment: I mean there can be many rows with embeeded tables. I updated my question with highlights.

Comment: Without an example of what your dataset looks like, I cant help you.